# Place tree-levels labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would like to accompany my tree with a column of labels on the right side of it. That is, to mark ‘level 0’, ‘level 1’ ... etc. Something like:

```
        *         ... level 0
       / \
      /   \     
     *     *      ... level 1
          / \
         *   *    ... level 2
```

However, I don’t know even how to get start with it. If I place a node somewhere and use it for reference, then the surrounding lines are shadowed (even though I didn’t place any text on it). Furthermore, I am still unaware of how to calculate places that labels should be.

The tree is

```
\coordinate(0)
    child {
       child
       child {
            child
            child
       }
     }
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: would you like to upvote the answer if it met your requirement

Comment: @jsbibra Sure. BTW, I noticed that `(b -| a0)` syntax. Does it have a name? Or where can I find reference on it?

Comment: you could read the excellent tutorial in the pgf manual at section 5 onwards -- as also in section 13.3 -- the manual --https://ctan.asis.ai/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[
  linecolor=cyan,
  linewidth=2pt,
  roundcorner=5pt,
  innertopmargin=2pt,
  innerbottommargin=2pt,
]{myframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1}]
\node [circle,draw] (z){$n$}
  child {node[circle,draw](a){a}
        child {node[circle, draw](b){b}}
        child {node[circle,draw](c){c}
              child {node[circle,draw](d){d}}
              child {node[circle,draw](e){e}}
    }
  }
;
\path (a) ++(1.5in,0)coordinate(a0)  node [thick] {$\cdots$} ++(1in,0)  node [] {Level 1};
\node at (b -| a0)(b0) {$\cdots$} (b0)++(1in,0)  node [] {Level 2};
\node at (d -| a0)(d0) {$\cdots$} (d0)++(1in,0)  node [] {Level 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```